# What's the return type of std::list<T>::begin() in C++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I guess this information can be derived by taking a deep look inside the `<list>` implementation, that's what I've done for the last day.

My problem is that I want a method of my `template<class T>` (which have a private `std::list<T>` member) to wrap...but I cannot figure out which return value give to this method.

My code look like this:

```cpp
template &lt;class T &gt;
    class MyTemplate {
       std::list&lt;T&gt; myList;
       ...

       somereturnvaluehere myMethod(){
              return myList.begin();       
       }
       ...

}
```

Comment: You should be easily able to see this in the `<list>` header file

Comment: or on the http://en.cppreference.com, MSDN, or many other websites.

Comment: or from any reasonable learning resource for the C++ standard library (and thus any good C++ learning resource). Before delving into the implementation of the standard library, you should rather try to understand the usage of the standard library first, which iterators are major part of.

Comment: actually, my problem was about the `typename` thing...but yeah, I have to understand stl deeply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list's `begin` will return a `std::list<T>::iterator`.

In your case it will be a dependent type, so `somereturnvaluehere` should be

```
typename std::list<T>::iterator
```

Comment: Then it would be a `const_iterator`, but `myMethod` isn't const here, so it will not happen in the example code.

Answer (score 8):

It is either

- `typename std::list<T>::iterator`,  (non-const version)
- or `typename std::list<T>::const_iterator` (const version)

depending on whether `myList` is a `const` object or not, though in your case, it doesn't seem to be a `const` object, which means you should use the first version, the non-const version.

In C++11, you don't need to worry about it, as if you want, you may use trailing-return type as:

```
auto myMethod() -> decltype(myList.begin())
{
    return myList.begin();       
}
```

But then I think, for your case, this is overkill, and in fact, makes things unnecessarily complicate than required. So I would suggest you not to use it; but just know that there is such a thing called *trailing-return-type* in C++11, whose usage may be justified in *certain* cases.

Answer (score 3):

It is either

```
std::list<T>::iterator;
```

or

```
std::list<T>::const_iterator;
```

depending on whether your list is `const` or not. You can use the type in your class like this:

```
struct Foo {
    typedef typename std::list<SomeType>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::list<SomeType>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator foo() { return m_list.begin();}
    const_iterator foo() const { return m_list.begin(); }

    std::list<SomeType> m_list;
};
```

Comment: if your demo showed both const and nonconst versions that'd be good.

Comment: @MooingDuck i was adding that while you were typing :-)

Answer (score 1):

`std::list<T>::begin()` will return you either a `std::list<T>::iterator` or a `std::list<T>::const_iterator` as others have said.

What's possibly more important is *what are you trying to acheive* from the `myMethod()` function?

If you're simply writing a thin wrapper around a `std::list` then I'm not sure I see the value. Ideally, you would encapsulate the list within your class so that its implementation is not exposed.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it will be `std::list<T>::iterator`.  But in order to present a cleaner API, and allow yourself some flexibility to change this in the future, you may want to define your own typedef (that maps to `std::list<T>::iterator`) and use that as the return type.  I.e.:

```
template <class T >
    class MyTemplate {
       std::list<T> myList;
       typedef std::list<T>::iterator iterator;
       ...

       iterator myMethod(){
              return myList.begin();       
       }
       ...

}
```

Here, I've named the typedef just `iterator`, which means that users of your class will refer to it as `MyTemplate<T>::iterator` -- but depending on what `myMethod()` does and the details of your class, you might want to name it something more specific.

By using a `typedef`, if you later change your mind and decide that you want to use a `std::vector` rather than a `std::list`, then your user's code should not need to be changed (though it will of course need to be recompiled).